# How to show JSON data in Horizontal scroll view with POST method?

Tags: json, flutter, api

I want to show my JSON data with a horizontal view instead of a listview, after running the following its doesn't show any error neither showing my data. But I'm getting data in console.

Firstly I create my API `Services()` and call it in `initState()` method so, my data display as soon as the app open.

```
  class Services{
  static const String url = 'http://medbo.digitalicon.in/api/medboapi/alldoctor';
  static Future<List<MyDoc>> getDocFun() async{
    try{
      final response = await http.post(url);
      if(200 == response.statusCode){
        print(response.body);//getting response in console
        final List<MyDoc> docs = myDocFromJson(response.body) as List<MyDoc>;
        return docs;
      }else{
        // return List<MyDoc>();
      }
    }catch(e){
      
    }
    return <MyDoc>[];
  }
}
```

calling it `initState(){}`

```
 Services.getDocFun().then((docs){
  setState(() {
         _docsVar =docs;
  });
}
);
```

After that in `build(BuildContext context)` I took a container where I call my `DoctorCard()` to show my JSON data in Horizontal view.

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
Widget image_carousel = new Container(
  margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
  // padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
  height: 180,
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
  // color: Colors.green,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
    shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
  ),

  child: Carousel(
    boxFit: BoxFit.contain,
    images: [
      AssetImage('assets/images/medbo-doctors.png'),
      AssetImage('assets/images/medbo-pathological-tests.png'),
      AssetImage('assets/images/medbo-home-banner.png'),
      AssetImage('assets/images/medbo-surgical-packages.png'),
    ],
    dotSize: 0.0,
    indicatorBgPadding: 0.0,
    autoplay: true,
  ),
);

return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
      flexibleSpace: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.topLeft,
            end: Alignment.topRight,
            colors: [
              Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              Theme.of(context).accentColor
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      title: Text(
        'HOME',
        style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Roboto_Condensed'),
      )),
  drawer: SideDrawer(),
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Container(
      color: Colors.lightBlue[50],
      child: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        children: [
          ClipPath(
            clipper: MyClipper(),
            child: Container(
              height: 400,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                  begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                  end: Alignment.center,
                  colors: [
                    Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                    Theme.of(context).accentColor
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Column(children: [
            image_carousel,
            Container(
              height: 200,
              // color: Colors.blue,
              child: ListView.separated(
                itemCount: 5,
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
                    // color: Colors.green,
                    height: 100,
                    width: 300,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                      gradient: LinearGradient(
                        begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                        end: Alignment.center,
                        colors: [
                          Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                          Theme.of(context).accentColor
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          height: 50,
                          width: 150,
                          // color: Colors.green,
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                'Your Last Visit',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    fontSize: 20,
                                    fontFamily: 'Roboto_Condensed',
                                    color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                              Text('Date and Time:',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 15,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontFamily: 'Roboto_Condensed')),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 40,
                        ),
                        //=============================================================1st row===========================================================================
                        Container(
                          height: 70,
                          // color: Colors.green,
                          child: Row(
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                width: 145,
                                // color: Colors.black,
                                child: Column(
                                  mainAxisAlignment:
                                      MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  crossAxisAlignment:
                                      CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    Text(
                                      'Doctors Name',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                          fontSize: 20,
                                          fontFamily: 'Roboto_Condensed',
                                          color: Colors.white),
                                    ),
                                    Text('Doctor_speciality',
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            fontFamily: 'Roboto_Condensed',
                                            fontSize: 15,
                                            color: Colors.white)),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                width: 10,
                              ),
                              Container(
                                width: 145,
                                // color: Colors.black,
                                child: InkWell(
                                  onTap: () {
                                    Navigator.push(
                                      context,
                                      MaterialPageRoute(
                                          builder: (context) =>
                                              LastVisit()),
                                    );
                                    // print("tapped on container");
                                  },
                                  child: Container(
                                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                    height: 38,
                                    // color: Colors.green,
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                                        borderRadius:
                                            BorderRadius.circular(5)),
                                    child: Text(
                                      'Details:',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                          fontSize: 15,
                                          color: Theme.of(context)
                                              .primaryColor),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    )),
                separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                    const Divider(
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 25,
             
            ),

      //==================================================================My Doc List UI part============================================================================================
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 18.0),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "Top Doctors",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        // fontFamily: 'Roboto_Condensed',
                        fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                  ),
                  Spacer(),
                  Text(
                    "View all",
                    style: TextStyle( 
                        fontSize: 13,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        // fontFamily: 'Roboto_Condensed',
                        fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 15.0,),
            Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height:200.0,
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount:_docsVar.length,
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemBuilder: (context,index){
                  MyDoc docs = _docsVar[index];
                  return DoctorCard();
                },
              ),

            ),






            SizedBox(height: 25.0,),
```

My `DoctorCard();` insted of showing dummy text data and image I want to show the data from Json

```
    class DoctorCard extends StatefulWidget {
  const DoctorCard({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DoctorCardState createState() => _DoctorCardState();
}

class _DoctorCardState extends State<DoctorCard> {
  //   Future<List<dynamic>> fetchData() async {//============================================fetchData() function
  //   final response = await http.post("http://medbo.digitalicon.in/api/medboapi/alldoctor");
  //   // return json.decode(response.body);
  //   Map<String, dynamic> map = json.decode(response.body);
  //   return map["Data"];
  // }



  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 18.0, bottom: 2.0),
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
      ),
      child: Container(
        width: 150.0,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(14.0),
                child: Image.asset('assets/images/medbo-doctors.png',
                    fit: BoxFit.cover),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 12.0,
            ),
            Text(
              "Dr. Tuhin",
              overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
              maxLines: 1,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 6.0),
            Text(
              "Specialist",
              overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
              maxLines: 1,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center   ,
              ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My model class

```
 // To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final myDoc = myDocFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

MyDoc myDocFromJson(String str) => MyDoc.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String myDocToJson(MyDoc data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class MyDoc {
    MyDoc({
        required this.status,
        required this.message,
        required this.data,
    });

    String status;
    String message;
    List<Datum> data;

    factory MyDoc.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => MyDoc(
        status: json["Status"],
        message: json["Message"],
        data: List<Datum>.from(json["Data"].map((x) => Datum.fromJson(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "Status": status,
        "Message": message,
        "Data": List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
}

class Datum {
    Datum({
        required this.doctorId,
        required this.encDoctorId,
        required this.doctorName,
        required this.doctorImage,
        this.linkPartner,
        required this.specialisation,
        this.gender,
        required this.qualification,
        this.fee,
        this.discountedFee,
        this.bookingFee,
        this.timeFrom,
        this.timeTo,
        this.visitDay,
        this.phone,
        this.alternatePhone,
        this.email,
        this.note,
        this.createBy,
        this.createDate,
        this.modBy,
        this.modDate,
        this.activeStatus,
        this.permission,
    });

    String doctorId;
    String encDoctorId;
    String doctorName;
    String doctorImage;
    dynamic linkPartner;
    String specialisation;
    dynamic gender;
    String qualification;
    dynamic fee;
    dynamic discountedFee;
    dynamic bookingFee;
    dynamic timeFrom;
    dynamic timeTo;
    dynamic visitDay;
    dynamic phone;
    dynamic alternatePhone;
    dynamic email;
    dynamic note;
    dynamic createBy;
    dynamic createDate;
    dynamic modBy;
    dynamic modDate;
    dynamic activeStatus;
    dynamic permission;

    factory Datum.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Datum(
        doctorId: json["DoctorId"],
        encDoctorId: json["EncDoctorId"],
        doctorName: json["DoctorName"],
        doctorImage: json["DoctorImage"],
        linkPartner: json["LinkPartner"],
        specialisation: json["Specialisation"],
        gender: json["Gender"],
        qualification: json["Qualification"],
        fee: json["Fee"],
        discountedFee: json["DiscountedFee"],
        bookingFee: json["BookingFee"],
        timeFrom: json["TimeFrom"],
        timeTo: json["TimeTo"],
        visitDay: json["VisitDay"],
        phone: json["Phone"],
        alternatePhone: json["AlternatePhone"],
        email: json["Email"],
        note: json["Note"],
        createBy: json["CreateBy"],
        createDate: json["CreateDate"],
        modBy: json["ModBy"],
        modDate: json["ModDate"],
        activeStatus: json["ActiveStatus"],
        permission: json["Permission"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "DoctorId": doctorId,
        "EncDoctorId": encDoctorId,
        "DoctorName": doctorName,
        "DoctorImage": doctorImage,
        "LinkPartner": linkPartner,
        "Specialisation": specialisation,
        "Gender": gender,
        "Qualification": qualification,
        "Fee": fee,
        "DiscountedFee": discountedFee,
        "BookingFee": bookingFee,
        "TimeFrom": timeFrom,
        "TimeTo": timeTo,
        "VisitDay": visitDay,
        "Phone": phone,
        "AlternatePhone": alternatePhone,
        "Email": email,
        "Note": note,
        "CreateBy": createBy,
        "CreateDate": createDate,
        "ModBy": modBy,
        "ModDate": modDate,
        "ActiveStatus": activeStatus,
        "Permission": permission,
    };
}
```

My JSON response

```
    {
    "Status": "1",
    "Message": "5 doctors found.",
    "Data": [
        {
            "DoctorId": "9",
            "EncDoctorId": "fXVmzecGStqrhx1PmIgwlQ==",
            "DoctorName": "Dr Ram Das",
            "DoctorImage": "http://medbo.digitalicon.in/Doctor/U7MK2MZGD0QVQ7E8IR7N.jpg",
            "LinkPartner": null,
            "Specialisation": "ENT",
            "Gender": null,
            "Qualification": "kj",
            "Fee": null,
            "DiscountedFee": null,
            "BookingFee": null,
            "TimeFrom": null,
            "TimeTo": null,
            "VisitDay": null,
            "Phone": null,
            "AlternatePhone": null,
            "Email": null,
            "Note": null,
            "CreateBy": null,
            "CreateDate": null,
            "ModBy": null,
            "ModDate": null,
            "ActiveStatus": null,
            "Permission": null
        },
        {
            "DoctorId": "5",
            "EncDoctorId": "pEl2B9kuumKRxIxLJO76eQ==",
            "DoctorName": "Dr.  Steve Buckner",
            "DoctorImage": "http://medbo.digitalicon.in/Doctor/IT02Z92IHFI48TMV6BUM.jpg",
            "LinkPartner": null,
            "Specialisation": "Eye",
            "Gender": null,
            "Qualification": "Frcs, md, mbbs",
            "Fee": null,
            "DiscountedFee": null,
            "BookingFee": null,
            "TimeFrom": null,
            "TimeTo": null,
            "VisitDay": null,
            "Phone": null,
            "AlternatePhone": null,
            "Email": null,
            "Note": null,
            "CreateBy": null,
            "CreateDate": null,
            "ModBy": null,
            "ModDate": null,
            "ActiveStatus": null,
            "Permission": null
        },
        {
            "DoctorId": "8",
            "EncDoctorId": "kFgorcFF0G6RQD4W+LwWnQ==",
            "DoctorName": "Dr. Alim Darr",
            "DoctorImage": "http://medbo.digitalicon.in/Doctor/VX4Q79ONBLQWIQ1ILQHF.jpg",
            "LinkPartner": null,
            "Specialisation": "ENT",
            "Gender": null,
            "Qualification": "FRCS",
            "Fee": null,
            "DiscountedFee": null,
            "BookingFee": null,
            "TimeFrom": null,
            "TimeTo": null,
            "VisitDay": null,
            "Phone": null,
            "AlternatePhone": null,
            "Email": null,
            "Note": null,
            "CreateBy": null,
            "CreateDate": null,
            "ModBy": null,
            "ModDate": null,
            "ActiveStatus": null,
            "Permission": null
        },
        {
            "DoctorId": "1",
            "EncDoctorId": "I3uXyzcuDZf21SSe5fHnSQ==",
            "DoctorName": "Dr. Mrs. Kusum Kumari Das",
            "DoctorImage": "http://medbo.digitalicon.in/Doctor/JVMK97QT9PSB8KQQ7NK1.jpg",
            "LinkPartner": null,
            "Specialisation": "ENT, Interventional Cardiology, Medicine, Orthopetic, Specialisation, Endocrenology, Jeriasistic",
            "Gender": null,
            "Qualification": "MBBS DM (Cardiology)",
            "Fee": null,
            "DiscountedFee": null,
            "BookingFee": null,
            "TimeFrom": null,
            "TimeTo": null,
            "VisitDay": null,
            "Phone": null,
            "AlternatePhone": null,
            "Email": null,
            "Note": null,
            "CreateBy": null,
            "CreateDate": null,
            "ModBy": null,
            "ModDate": null,
            "ActiveStatus": null,
            "Permission": null
        },
        {
            "DoctorId": "2",
            "EncDoctorId": "7Ch2aVnhokZtRWyJtuDA/A==",
            "DoctorName": "Dr. Rejaul Alam",
            "DoctorImage": "http://medbo.digitalicon.in/Doctor/INFX2N9V5QFH712M2LEE.jpg",
            "LinkPartner": null,
            "Specialisation": "Orthopetic, Specialisation",
            "Gender": null,
            "Qualification": "MD, DM",
            "Fee": null,
            "DiscountedFee": null,
            "BookingFee": null,
            "TimeFrom": null,
            "TimeTo": null,
            "VisitDay": null,
            "Phone": null,
            "AlternatePhone": null,
            "Email": null,
            "Note": null,
            "CreateBy": null,
            "CreateDate": null,
            "ModBy": null,
            "ModDate": null,
            "ActiveStatus": null,
            "Permission": null
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: hey, I updated the code, still not able to display the Json data although I'm getting responses in my console. What will be the syntax I should use in `DoctorCard` to show the data?

Answer (score 0):

1- Add the data you have taken with api or json to the list you have created

2- You added itemCount:doctorList.length to itemCount: parameter of listview.builder, but I see a comment line there. without it listview.builder won't work.

3- You can request the data by using the index given by listview.builder for DoctorCard().

If you write all the codes, including the missing codes, we will help you more clearly.

Comment: Hey, I updated the code, and I'm getting data in my console. what syntax I should use in `DoctorCard` to display data in my app?

Comment: I have a todo crud example on my github, both json related examples and creat, read, update, delete operations linked to api are available as examples. I think you removed the listview in your code, but I could not see it, but if you examine my examples, you can succeed.

my github https://github.com/gulmensedat/todoapp-crudful

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell your `DoctorCard` widget what data to show, and then use this data when displaying image, name etc. There are many ways, but one is adding a constructor parameter to `DoctorCard` with the doctor data that it needs to show. You also have to use `Image.network` instead of `Image.asset` and add `itemCount` that is currently commented out in your code.

I will assume that `doctorList` contains the array that is returned from `fetchData`.

`DoctorCard` class:

```
class DoctorCard extends StatefulWidget {
  final dynamic doctor;
  const DoctorCard({Key? key, this.doctor}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DoctorCardState createState() => _DoctorCardState();
}
```

`ListView.builder` in your `Container`:

```
child: ListView.builder(
  itemCount: doctorList.length,
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
  shrinkWrap: true,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return DoctorCard(doctor: doctorList[index]);
  },
),
```

`Column` in `_DoctorCardState.build`:

```
child: Column(
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(14.0),
        child: Image.network(widget.doctor["DoctorImage"],
            fit: BoxFit.cover),
      ),
    ),
    SizedBox(
      height: 12.0,
    ),
    Text(
      widget.doctor["DoctorName"],
      overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
      maxLines: 1,
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    ),
    SizedBox(height: 6.0),
    Text(
      widget.doctor["Specialisation"],
      overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
      maxLines: 1,
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    ),
  ],
),
```

Comment: Hey, I updated my code , although I'm not getting DoctorName in my DoctorCard with this syntax ` widget.doctor["DoctorName"],`

Comment: With you original code and performing steps in my answer it worked for me. Now you return a `List<MyDoc>`, but in fact your doctors are inside `data` of `MyDoc`. And if it is no longer a map, the syntax is `doctor.DoctorName`, but only if a `doctor` is one element of the array within `data` in your response.